# localhost.localdomainに対する正引きがうまくされない

Tags: centos, dns

参考サイト：http://www.obenri.com/_dnsserver/named_test.html

ループバックアドレスに対する逆引きの名前解決を行いたいと思い、
下記のコマンドを実行しました。

```
[root@localhost ~]# host -a localhost.localdomain
Trying "localhost.localdomain"
Received 114 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53 in 1784 ms
Trying "localhost.localdomain"
Host localhost.localdomain not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 114 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53 in 1998 ms
```

通常であれば; ANSWER SECTION: に127.0.0.1の表記が表示されると考えましたが、
not foundの表記がでてしまいます。

設定のどの部分がおかしいのかご教授いただければと思います。

なお、named.confの設定は下記です。

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        version         "unknown";
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query{
                    127.0.0.1;
                    192.168.1.0/24;
        };
        allow-recursion{
                    127.0.0.1;
                    192.168.1.0/24;
        };
        allow-transfer{
                    127.0.0.1;
                    192.168.1.0/24;
        };


        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
        forwarders{
                192.168.1.1;
                XXX.XXX.XX.XXX;
                XXX.XXX.XX.XX;
        };

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel "default-log" {
                file "/var/log/named/default.log" versions 5 size 10M;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };

        category default { "default-log"; };
};



view "internal" {
        match-clients { 192.168.1.0/24; };
        match-destinations { 192.168.1.0/24; };

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/named.hogehoge.dip.jp.zone";
};

view "external" {
        match-clients { any; };
        match-destinations { any; };
        recursion no;
        include "/etc/named.hogehoge.dip.jp.zone.wan";
};
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: localhostは/etc/hostsから引くのがふつうでしょう。192.168.1.1でDNSサーバを独自に立ち上げて、localdomainを登録したけれどうまく引けないということですか？ならばbindの設定をみないとわかりません。

Comment: @Kenji Noguchiさん
bindの設定はnamed.confの設定を見せればいいということでしょうか。
初歩的な質問ですいませんがよろしくおねがいいたします。

メインの方に文章にnamed.confの内容いれます。

Answer (score 2):

設定に、localdomainのゾーン情報が定義されていません。

OSによってはlocaldomainのゾーン情報がデフォルトで設定されているものがあり、その場合は何もしなくてもlocalhostの名前解決が出来ますが、そうでない場合は自分で設定する必要があります。

DNS(特にbind)は設定を誤ると重大なセキュリティ上の問題が生じますので、闇雲に試すのではなく、一通りのことが説明されている資料を参照しそれを理解した上で利用されることを強くお勧めします。